# Have ArrayAdapter with list of objects to show objects containing string in a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a normal ListView:

```
<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:dividerHeight="10dp" />
```

And I populate that listview with an ArrayList of Alert objects:

```
// Get ListView object from XML
listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

// Create a new Adapter
ArrayAdapter<Alert> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Alert>(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, android.R.id.text1, DataSourceHandler.getAlertsList());

// Assign adapter to ListView
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

DataSourceHandler.getAlertsList() returns to me the ArrayList of objects and in my ListView I now see two items like this:

- path.to.object@41a92a48
- path.to.object@41a92cc8

Those two Alert objects has a method called getName() which returns a String that I want to use as the displaying name for this item in the list instead of what I get above.

How can I do this?

Comment: can you add `getAlertsList()` method?

Comment: you need to override `toString()` in your object class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As was already mentioned in the comments, the standard `ArrayAdapter` implementation calls `toString()` on every object in your list and populates the view using the resulting `String`. The simplest solution will be to override `toString()` by calling your `getName()` method inside it. If it doesn't suit your needs then you should create a custom adapter.

Answer (score 3):

Yes,override `toString()` is the solution, example of doing that:

[Example](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/binding-android-listview-with-custom-objects-using-arrayadapter)